# Why no value is being set for nullable and optional parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying following code.

```
TestMethod(null, null);    

public static void TestMethod(int? x = 10, int? y = 20)
        {
            var message = $"The value of x is {x.Value} and y is {y.Value}";
        }
```

I am not able to understand why the Value property of `x` is `null` despite I have set their default values in parameters?

[image: Nullable & Optional Parameter]

Comment: You specifically passed `null` and `null` to the method, therefore, `x` and `y` don't have values. If you want to use the default values, you shouldn't pass anything at all (i.e., `TestMethod();`).

Comment: You are passing "null" as the input parameters for the method.....

Comment: Do you want some value to be used when `null` is passed? Then simply do check for `null` in body of method. Optional parameters are for when you omit them upon call, `null` is not omitting, it's a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carefully (re)-read the concept:

When you say

```
void TestMethod(int? x = 10, int? y = 20)
```

The ? means that datatype is Nullable<T> - meaning it can be assigned as Null.

Having some default values initialized in the function signature means that if you DO NOT pass anything, then the default values will be taken.

So in your case if you just call the method like

```
TestMethod();
```

Then the default values come into play.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the current Nullable object if the HasValue property is true. An exception is thrown if the HasValue property is false.
[Nullable.Value Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=netframework-4.8)

Your default value is getting overwritten with `null` when you call `TestMethod(null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed a value. Understanding `null` is not always easy. It means unkown value, but not knowing a value is very close to not having that value, so this leads to confusion. `int?` can be `null`, so passing a `null` to the method is legal and is different from not passing a value. However, since `int?` can be `null`, if you pass `null` to it, which is a legal action, as discussed earlier, then you specify that you want that parameter to be `null` at method call, so, if the default would override the `null` that you passed, then the language would stop obeying you (it's like a Skynet thing in the Terminator, analogous to the machine gaining consciousness and rebelling against its master). So, if you call `TestMethod()`, then the default values will apply. Now, I understand your point that you do not want to care of nulls and if you have such nulls, then you intend to use the defaults, however, this intention is part of business logic and we shouldn't expect this behavior from the language itself. You can do something like this:

```
public static void TestMethodWrapper(int? x = 10, int? y = 20) {
    if ((x == null) && (y == null)) {
        return TestMethod();
    } else if (y == null) {
        return TestMethod(x);
    }
    return TestMethod(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your issue like this:

```
public static void TestMethod(int? x = null, int? y = null)
{
    if (x == null) x = 10;
    if (y == null) y = 10;
    string message = $"The value of x is {x.Value} and y is {y.Value}";
}
```

OR:

```
public static void TestMethod(int? x = default, int? y = default)
{
    if (x == null) x = 10;
    if (y == null) y = 10;
    string message = $"The value of x is {x.Value} and y is {y.Value}";
}
```

**Important points when working with `Nullable` types**

1. `int?` is the same as `Nullable<int>`. It is a class which may be holds a value type for you.
2. Since `Nullable<int>` class, a variable of this type is not a value type, it is a reference type. This means it can be set to null, and its default value is null (by default I mean when using the new `default` keyword)
3. If you set a standard value for an input parameter in your method, the variable will assume that value only when you do not pass the variable to the method. If you pass `null`, the variable will be set to `null`.
4. I usually compare nullable types with `null` for checking whether its value is set or not, like: `if (x == null)`. The `x.HasValue` way is pretty pointless, because when `x` is `null`, you'll get a nice `NullReferenceException`.

**Example**

This is the time when analysing the execution of a program helps more than a thousands words. Check the below example for understanding the many possibilities you get when working with `Nullable` types.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodA(null);
            MethodA(default);
            MethodA(new int?());
            MethodA(5);

            Console.WriteLine();

            MethodB();
            MethodB(null);
            MethodB(default);
            MethodB(new int?());
            MethodB(5);

            Console.WriteLine();

            MethodC();
            MethodC(null);
            MethodC(default);
            MethodC(new int?());
            MethodC(5);

            Console.WriteLine();

            MethodD();
            MethodD(null);
            MethodD(default);
            MethodD(new int?());
            MethodD(5);
        }

        private static void MethodA(int? x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MethodA({x?.ToString() ?? "null"})");

            if (x == null)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is null");
            else if (!x.HasValue)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, but an integer value is not set on it");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, and its integer value is '{x.Value}'");

            int x2 = x ?? 10;
            Console.WriteLine($"x2 = {x2}");
        }

        public static void MethodB(int? x = 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MethodB({x?.ToString() ?? "null"})");

            if (x == null)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is null");
            else if (!x.HasValue)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, but an integer value is not set on it");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, and its integer value is '{x.Value}'");
        }

        public static void MethodC(int? x = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MethodC({x?.ToString() ?? "null"})");

            if (x == null)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is null");
            else if (!x.HasValue)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, but an integer value is not set on it");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, and its integer value is '{x.Value}'");
        }

        public static void MethodD(int? x = default)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MethodD({x?.ToString() ?? "null"})");

            if (x == null)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is null");
            else if (!x.HasValue)
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, but an integer value is not set on it");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"x is not null, and its integer value is '{x.Value}'");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MethodA(null)
x is null
x2 = 10
MethodA(null)
x is null
x2 = 10
MethodA(null)
x is null
x2 = 10
MethodA(5)
x is not null, and its integer value is '5'
x2 = 5

MethodB(10)
x is not null, and its integer value is '10'
MethodB(null)
x is null
MethodB(null)
x is null
MethodB(null)
x is null
MethodB(5)
x is not null, and its integer value is '5'

MethodC(null)
x is null
MethodC(null)
x is null
MethodC(null)
x is null
MethodC(null)
x is null
MethodC(5)
x is not null, and its integer value is '5'

MethodD(null)
x is null
MethodD(null)
x is null
MethodD(null)
x is null
MethodD(null)
x is null
MethodD(5)
x is not null, and its integer value is '5'
```

Remember to set the following configuration in your project settings for enabling the latest version of the C# language, including the `default` keyword used in the example above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAcoKgW1QOzgBsiBjACwlIGsBLfAcwBoATEAagB8ABAJgEYAsAChuAZgAEfCQGEJAbxETlEpcvFT+ANikAWCQBUUMALIQY5APYsAFPRgB+CQA8JAXgn8ADEwn2nAJ7uErxeAJRqKiqKwlFxKgBuWBI4KMhQDBDBACQARAaUEklEcFmWYC5+yArOAHQAalAlEAC+ElD4LBJBtNXyAQ1NpS25ANyRcS0TExrc+iY2YQoTUSsqRsim5la2hCS+e0Rh47HxhsZmFtaLJ2eqp8pTwi1AA), you can see the difference when specifying default values, or when not.

The following source:

```
using System;
public class C {

   public static void TestMethod(int? x = 10, int? y = 20)
        {
            var message = $"The value of x is {x.Value} and y is {y.Value}";
        }

    public void M() {

        TestMethod(null, null);
        TestMethod();

    }
}
```

Generates the following (hidden) code for method M():

```
public void M()
{
    TestMethod(null, null);
    TestMethod(10, 20);
}
```

It is even more clear, if you look at the IL generated:

```
.method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2084
        // Code size 46 (0x2e)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldloca.s 0  // Parameter x = null
        IL_0003: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
        IL_0009: ldloc.0     
        IL_000a: ldloca.s 0  // Parameter y = null
        IL_000c: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
        IL_0012: ldloc.0
        IL_0013: call void C::TestMethod(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>)
        IL_0018: nop
        IL_0019: ldc.i4.s 10  // Parameter x = 10
        IL_001b: newobj instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
        IL_0020: ldc.i4.s 20  // Parameter y = 20
        IL_0022: newobj instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
        IL_0027: call void C::TestMethod(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>)
        IL_002c: nop
        IL_002d: ret
    } // end of method C::M
```

As you can see, the default values specified, are used in the code to generate the call, not in the method itself.

[Click this link, to see for yourself.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAcoKgW1QOzgBsiBjACwlIGsBLfAcwBoATEAagB8ABAJgEYAsAChuAZgAEfCQGEJAbxETlEpcvFT+ANikAWCQBUUMALIQY5APYsAFPRgB+CQA8JAXgn8ADEwn2nAJ7uErxeAJRqKiqKwlFxKgBuWBI4KMhQDBDBACQARAaUEklEcFmWYC5+yArOAHQAalAlEAC+ElD4LBJBtNXyAQ1NpS25ANyRcS0TExrc+iY2YQoTUSsqRsim5la2hCS+e0Rh47HxhsZmFtaLJ2eqp8pTwi1AA)